# jQuery: Switching from addEventListener to bind

Tags: jquery, this, bind, addeventlistener

The original code:

```
this.control.addEventListener('click', $.proxy(function() {
    this.time.hashours = (this.duration() / 3600) >= 1.0;
    this.time.duration.text(getTime(this.duration(), this.controls.time.hasHours));
    this.time.current.text(getTime(0, this.controls.time.hasHours));
}, this));
```

The attempt at cross-browser support:

```
$(this.control).bind('click', $.proxy(function(e) {
    var o = e.delegateTarget;
    o.time.hashours = (o.duration() / 3600) >= 1.0;
    o.time.duration.text(getTime(o.duration(), o.controls.time.hasHours));
    o.time.current.text(getTime(0, o.controls.time.hasHours));
}, this));
```

Even with the proxy, the context of this no longer belongs to the calling object because of jQuery's custom event model. How can I get the original `this.control`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even with the proxy, the context of this no longer belongs to the calling object because of jQuery's custom event model.

I don't think jQuery's custom event model is the problem here. When you proxy the callback function, the `this` value should refer to the root object that contains `control` and other properties such as `ctime` and `time` as in your original example.

In other words, don't try to get the original object like this from the `delegateTarget`

```
var o = e.delegateTarget;
o.time.hashours = (o.duration() / 3600) >= 1.0;
...
```

but just stick to your original code,

```
this.time.hashours = (this.duration() / 3600) >= 1.0;
```

Checkout this minimal [example](http://jsfiddle.net/B7FAk/) that resembles your structure.

Comment: You're right. Using `.on` instead of `.bind` works with the `$.proxy`, thanks!

Comment: @BrianGraham - `bind` and `on` don't have any functional difference for this particular example. It was probably something else that was causing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but jQuery's custom event object includes the original event. It is accessible like so: `e.originalEvent` where `e` is the jQuery event.

Also, just FYI, as of jQuery 1.7, the `.on` method is preferred over `.bind` see: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: When I use `var o = e.originalEvent;`, `o.time` is undefined.

Comment: Good point. I think @Anurag's answer is more what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `this.control` inside the `click` event handler then you should do something like this.

```
var $context = this;
$(this.control).bind('click', function(e) {
    //You can use $context here
    //var o = e.delegateTarget;
    $context.time.hashours = ($context.duration() / 3600) >= 1.0;
    $context.time.duration
    .text(getTime($context.duration(), $context.controls.time.hasHours));
    $context.time.current.text(getTime(0, $context.controls.time.hasHours));

    //And this will point to this.control on which the event is triggered
});
```